# InplaceSelect for Objects not Strings

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

## Form

```
 <h:inputText value="#{BackingBean.firstString}" />
 <h:inputText value="#{BackingBean.secondString}" />
 <rich:inplaceSelect value="#{BackingBean.myText}" defaultLabel="select">
  <f:selectItems value="#{???}" />
 </rich:inplaceSelect>
```

## BackingBean

```
private List<MyText> myText;
private String firstString;
private String secondString;
```

## MyText

```
private String id
private String desc
private String text
```

I want to select one MyText from list while in inplaceSelect I want to show only one field of MyText. What is best way to acheive it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need a [`Converter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) to convert between `MyText` and `String`. Based on your question history I understand that you're using JSF 1.2, so I'll give a JSF 1.2 targeted answer.

The `Converter` should *basically* look like this (it's just an example, read the comment how you're supposed to implement it):

```java
public class MyTextConverter implements Converter {

    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        // Write code here to convert MyText to its unique String representation.
        return String.valueOf(((MyText) value).getId());
    }

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        // Write code here to convert unique String representation of MyText to MyText object.
        return myTextService.find(Long.valueOf(value));
    }

}
```

Register it as follows in `faces-config.xml`:

```xml
<converter>
    <converter-for-class>com.example.model.MyText</converter-for-class>
    <converter-class>com.example.converter.MyTextConverter</converter-class>
</converter>
```

Then you can use the input as follows:

```html
<rich:inplaceSelect value="#{bean.myText}" defaultLabel="select">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.myTextItems}" />
</rich:inplaceSelect>
```

with

```
private MyText myText;
private List<SelectItem> myTextItems;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    myTextItems = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

    for (MyText myText : myTextService.list()) {
        myTextItems.add(new SelectItem(myText, myText.getText()));
    }
}

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In you backing-bean, since you have `<rich:inplaceSelect value="#{backingBean.myText}"`, change

```
private List<MyText> myText;
```

to

```
private MyText myText;
```

And add a list of `SelectItem`s in the backing-bean:

```
private List<SelectItem> selItems;
```

And then you can populate that list with `SelectItem`s either in the constructor or a method with (@PostConstruct).

You can use the constructor `SelectItem(Object value, String label)`.

```
selItems.add(new SelectItem(myTextObj, myTextObj.text)); //or id or desc instead of text
//...
```

And then in the view:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{backingBean.selItems}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<f:selectItems
    value="#{BackingBean.myTextID}"
    var="value"
    itemLabel="#{value.desc}"
    itemValue="#{item.id}"
    />
```

or whatever attributes you need to be the item label/value. JSF 2 required.